# Passing arbitrary data into a node prior to preprocessing

Tags: nodes, 8, theming

I am looking for a way of passing arbitrary data though `node_view()` to a preprocess function.

I am using the following code.

```
  $node = node_load(1);
  $node->mycustomdata = 'mydata'; // This is the data I want passed through.
  return node_view($node,  'teaser');
```

I want mycustomdata to be available to me inside my preprocess function so I can add it as a template variable.

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  $variables['mycustomdata'] = $node->mycustomdata; //  Here is where I want to access the data.
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Node's in D8 work differently to D7. in D7 node was a stdClass object - basically used in the same way an array was assign a value to a key ($node->value). In D8 Node's are proper objects and can't do the same key/value. Instead, how about creating a field on the node and assigning the value to the field, save the node and then view it?

Comment: The data is arbitrary so a field would not be suitable as the data can be of many different values and types. So i need to find another way of passing data through to the preprocess function if there is no way of attaching it via the NodeInterface, the data is also different depending on display_mode so the  data cannot be stored once per node and needs to be passed dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out this actually works, and the data does get passed through. Apologies for any time wasting.